# React.js: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I get an error "Body.js:22 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" when trying to add a new item. As backend i am using Ruby on Rails.

When i am trying to save data in console log it works perfectly, so data is transferred normally

```
 import React from 'react'
 import AllProducts from './AllProducts'
 import NewProduct from './NewProduct';
 class Body extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          products: []
        };
        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)
        this.addNewProduct = this.addNewProduct.bind(this)
    }
        handleFormSubmit(title, body,price){
        let productbody = JSON.stringify({product: {title: title, body:body,price: price} })
    
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/admin/products', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: productbody,
        }).then((response) => {return response.json()})
          .then((product)=>{this.addNewProduct(product)})
      }
      addNewProduct(product){
        this.setState({
            products: this.state.products.concat(product)
        })
      }
    
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('/admin/products.json')
          .then((response) => {return response.json()})
          .then((data) => {this.setState({ products: data }) });
      }
    render(){       console.log('I was triggered during render')
 

        return(
          <div>
              <NewProduct handleFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit} />
            <AllProducts products={this.state.products} />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    export default Body
```

NewProduct.js

```
import React from 'react'

const NewProduct = (props) => {
let formFields = {}



return(
  <form onSubmit={ (e) => { 
        e.preventDefault();
        props.handleFormSubmit(
          formFields.title.value,
          formFields.body.value,
          formFields.price.value

        ); 
        e.target.reset();}
    }>
    <input ref={input => formFields.title = input} placeholder='Enter the name of the item'/>
    <input ref={input => formFields.body = input} placeholder='Enter a description' />
    <input ref={input => formFields.price = input} placeholder='Enter a price' />

    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
)
}

      export default NewProduct
```

Edit:
line 22

```
:}).then((response) => {return response.json()})
```

So problem with format? But what do i need to do?

[image: Headers image]

[image: Headers image 2]

Comment: What's sent back? Which line is line 22?

Comment: The **first** thing to do here is to look in the browser console's network tab to see what the response to the `fetch` was (and then to include that if you post a question about it :-) ). Your code is open to the [`fetch` footgun](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) (it's not just you, a **lot** of code is) so you may be trying to parse something as JSON that isn't JSON.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder added screen of network tab, take a look, please

Comment: If that's the actual content, it's not JSON; JSON has quotes around property names in quotes etc.

Comment: Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247 Also, what you've shown is an **interpreted** version of what was sent back, not what was actually sent back. To see what was actually sent back, click the "view source" link shown on that panel.